# Does the National Neopian Bank actually limit withdraws?

Tags: neopets

It says under "Make a Withdrawal" that:

> If you withdraw Neopoints too many times a day, the bank staff may get angry and refuse to serve you! Withdraw wisely.

I've never withdrawn very many Neopoints, and I assume that there is no size limit to a single withdraw, but is there a limit to the quantity of them? What is it?

Comment: Another important National Neopian Economics question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Neopets Wiki](http://www.pinkpt.com/neodex/index.php/National_Neopian_Bank), you're limited to 15 withdrawals per day.